# How can I use bash's select on a newline-separated list?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, select

How can I use bash's select on a newline-separated list?

I'm actually trying to improve the following snippet in a working script:

```
# for example
nwd=/media/$USER/some-drive

# This makes a newline-separated list. I'm open to options that make a
# list in a different fashion. I usually loop with find -print0 for this
# kind of thing, but I don't know an easy way to omit a particular
# element ($nwd) from a null-separated list.
volumes="$( ls /media/$USER | grep -v "$( basename -- "$nwd" )" )"

# If there's only one option, I don't need the user to choose.
if [ 1 -eq "$( echo "$volumes" | wc -l )" ]; then
  mount_point="/media/$USER/$volumes"
else
  # KNOWN BUG: It is impossible to select devices with spaces in their names.
  echo "Please select the appropriate device:"
  select mount_point in $volumes Quit; do
    case "$mount_point" in
    Quit ) exit $EXIT_USER_HALT;;
    '' ) echo "Invalid option. Try another one." >&2;continue;;
    * ) break;;
    esac
  done
  mount_point="/media/$USER/$mount_point"
fi
```

Comment: Use an extended pattern instead to populate an array: `shopt -s extglob; volumes=( /media/$USER/!("$(basename -- "$nwd")") )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting `IFS=$'\n'`, your `list` will be split on newlines, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
list=$'one\ntwo\nthree'

IFS=$'\n'
select item in $list; do
    case "$item" in
        one) echo "1";;
        two) echo "2";;
        *) break;;
    esac
done
```

Be sure to either do this in a function with `local IFS`, or to restore `IFS` later manually.

If you expect your filenames (in the list) to contain pathname expansion pattern characters `*`, `?`, or `[`, you should wrap the `select` statement block above with `set -f` and `set +f` which will prevent those patterns to expand to pathnames. It'll also prevent the expansion of extended globs (if you enabled `extglob`).

Comment: This isn't necessarily safe, as `$list` is still subject to pathname expansion (and it excludes rare but legal pathnames that contain newline characters).

Comment: You're right, I've added a note about that (and how to prevent it).

Answer (score 4):

Using extended patterns, you can populate an array with the desired file names:

```
shopt -s extglob
nwd=/media/$USER/some-drive
volumes=( /media/$USER/!("$(basename -- "$nwd")") )
# Or more generally,
# volumes=( "$(dirname -- "$nwd")"/!("$(basename -- "$nwd")") )
```

Then you can use the array as

```
if (( ${#volumes[@]} == 1 )); then
    mount_point="/media/$USER/$volumes"  # or ${volumes[0]}
else
    echo "Please select the appropriate device:"
    select mount_point in "${volumes[@]}" Quit; do
        case $mount_point in
            Quit) exit $EXIT_USER_HALT ;;
            '') echo "Invalid option. Try another one." >&2; continue ;;
            *) break ;;
        esac
    done
fi
```

Using an array also fixes the inability to select mount points whose name contains a space. (In fact, it will work with *any* valid file path, including those that might contain glob metacharacters or newlines.)

Comment: These are both great answers. I'm actually going to use your solution since it seems more resilient and better bash style, although I decided to mark randomir's as the answer since he more directly answered the question. Thanks!